# htaccess paramameter with Rewriterule

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

example.com/category/.htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /category/

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NE,L]

RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)(?:/[^/]+)?/?$ load.php?cat=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/[^/]+/[^/]+/([0-9]+)/?$ load.php?cat=$1&p=$2 [L,QSA]
```

example.com/category/1995/english-videos/`page/2` <- this is pagination. but havent 2 number like this `example.com/category/1995/english-videos/page/` i want to 301 redirect to example.com/category/1995/english-videos this url. how to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To redirect within mod_rewrite, you need to define the `R` flag. To make it a permanent redirect, you need to set the flag to 301, like so: `R=301`. You already set RewriteBase, which is good. The only thing you need to do is match the url now. Replace the flag `R` below with `R=301` after you have tested the redirect thoroughly and it all works correctly.

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+/[^/]+/)page/?$ $1 [R,L]
```

Comment: where want to add this?

Comment: In your case I don't think the url is matched by any other rules, so anywhere should be fine. I always put redirects before internal rewrites to prevent internal rewrites messing with my url before I redirect, so put it under `RewriteBase` and above the other rules.

Comment: By default, it is a temporary (302) redirect. The upside of that, is that it isn't cached by the browser, so if you make a typo you can simply fix it and refresh the page, instead of needing to clear the browser cache. To make it permanent, you need to replace the flag as pointed out in the answer.